# Barcode Scanner python Opencv does not open web camera when executing for the second time

Tags: python, opencv, barcode

So i just want a reusable method when pressed will open camera and scan the qr code then close the camera and pass the scanned data to the calling method. I call this method from a button click, but the first time i press the button the web cam appears scans and passes the data and closes the window, but when i press the button again it does not open the camera nor an error is thrown. But if i stop the running script and execute it it will work fine until second time pressing the button... please help this is my code

```
def openscaner(self):
    valid_cams = []
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_V4L2)
    id = ""
    while True:
        check, frame = video.read()
        dec = decode(frame)
        print(dec)
        try:
            for obj in dec:
                print(obj)
                id = dec[0].data.decode()
                if id:
                    video.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    return id
        except:
            print("Error")
        cv2.imshow("Scan Barcodes - Web Came", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord("q"):
            break
    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return id
```

The calling method is like i just create the class and call the above method

```
    bb = Barcoded()
    id = bb.openscaner()
```

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the error?

Comment: but no error is thrown, let me elaborate: the first time i press the button it works well and retruns the barcode data plus closes the camera, but when i press the button again the blue light of my web cam turns on but no dialogue box appears it just hangs there.